# Magento Cart Get Custom Option (Text Field) Value in Model/Quote/Item.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My products have variable sizes which affect weight and I need to put weight logic in the cart to more accurately calculate shipping costs.  I've moved a copy of **app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item.php** to the local code pool.  I've been able to grab the associated product's base weight, however, I am not able to get the custom option (text field) value to do the math calculation before updating the cart.  I'm doing this in the public function, `setProduct`.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    public function setProduct($product)
    {
        if ($this->getQuote()) {
            $product->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
            $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());
        }

            //Get the Weight per UOM
                $sku = $product->getSku();
                $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
                $wpuom = $item->getResource()->getAttribute('weight_per_uom')->getFrontend()->getValue($item);

    //Get the Length
        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();
        /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product */
        $info = new Varien_Object($params);

        // Don't throw an exception if required options are missing
        $processMode = Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Abstract::PROCESS_MODE_LITE;

        $options = array();
        foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
            /* @var $option Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option */
            $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                ->setOption($option)
                ->setProduct($product)
                ->setRequest($info)
                ->setProcessMode($processMode)
                ->validateUserValue($info->getOptions());

            $optionValue = $info->getData('options/' . $option->getId());
            $options[] = array(
                'label' => $option->getTitle(),
                'value' => $group->getFormattedOptionValue($optionValue),
                'value2' => $option->getValues(),
                'option_id' => $option->getId(),
                'option_type' => $option->getType()
            );

//<<<This is Where I Cannot Get the Value for the Custom Option>>>

            if($options[0]['label'] == 'Length') {
                //print_r($options[0]['value']);
            }
        }

            //Update Weight
                $baseWeight = $item->getWeight();
                $uom = $item->getResource()->getAttribute('uom')->getFrontend()->getValue($item);

                if((($uom == 'Meters') && ($length >= 76)) || (($uom == 'Feet') && ($length >= 250))) { $spoolWeight = 3; }
                else { $spoolWeight = 0; }

                $finalWeight = ($baseWeight + ($length * $wpuom) + $spoolWeight);


        $this->setData('product', $product)
            ->setProductId($product->getId())
            ->setProductType($product->getTypeId())
            ->setSku($this->getProduct()->getSku())
            ->setName($product->getName())
            ->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
            ->setTaxClassId($product->getTaxClassId())
            ->setBaseCost($product->getCost())
            ->setIsRecurring($product->getIsRecurring());

        if ($product->getStockItem()) {
            $this->setIsQtyDecimal($product->getStockItem()->getIsQtyDecimal());
        }

        Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_quote_item_set_product', array(
            'product' => $product,
            'quote_item' => $this
        ));
        return $this;
    }
```

When I try adding `print_r($options[0]);`, I get everything except **value**, it's not even an array.  What am I missing in order to get the value?

Comment: A few side notes: Products are configurable and version is Magento 1.9.1 CE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're likely going to run into issues with the wishlist and other functionality if you display the product price in various spots on your site such as category pages, wishlist and other areas on the site.

That being said, I made some modifications to your code and updated it below.  I took a slightly different approach to get the end result.  First, get all the cart items for the current session.  If the product type is configurable, do some logic, if not, do other logic.  Inside the logic, I am gathering the items, associated attribute values, custom options, and custom option values.  I also added some functionality to add the length and the unit of measure to the sku.  Then I went ahead and showed examples of how you can use direct mySQL queries to update the database with your new pricing, skus, weight, and other details.

```
public function setProduct($product)
{
    if ($this->getQuote()) {
        $product->setStoreId($this->getQuote()->getStoreId());
        $product->setCustomerGroupId($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGroupId());
    }

    $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
    foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $itm){
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $item = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);
        $assocProd = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$itm->getSku());

        if($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') { //configurable product
            foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
                if($o->getTitle() == "YOUR CUSTOM OPTION LABEL" && $o->getType() == "field"){
                    $optionId = $o->getOptionId();
                    $opz = $itm->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
                    $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($opz ? unserialize($opz->getValue()) : null);
                    foreach($buyRequest['options'] as $key => $value){
                        if($key == $optionId) {
                            $length = $value;
                            //here is your length... do with it what you please
                            }

                            //example of how to update the database
                            $itemId = $itm->getId();

                            $query = 'UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET `weight` = "'.$finalWeight.'", `display_sku` = "'.$displaySku.'" WHERE `item_id` = "'.$itemId.'"';
                            $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                            $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                            $writeConnection->query($query);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else { //simple product
            if($product->getOptions()) { //has options
                foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) {
                    if($o->getTitle() == "YOUR OPTION LABEL" && $o->getType() == "field"){
                        $optionId = $o->getOptionId();
                        $opz = $itm->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
                        $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($opz ? unserialize($opz->getValue()) : null);
                        foreach($buyRequest['options'] as $key => $value){
                            $finalWeight = '';
                            if($key == $optionId) {
                                $length = $value;
                                //here's your length value for simple products
                                }

                                //to update the database
                                $itemId = $itm->getId();

                                $query = 'UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET `weight` = "'.$finalWeight.'", `display_sku` = "'.$displaySku.'" WHERE `item_id` = "'.$itemId.'"';
                                $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
                                $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
                                $writeConnection->query($query);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else { //doesn't have options
                //this would be your logic for a simple product with no options
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps and feel free to let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for including the query to update the database... you saved me another step!